# Why does nn.CrossEntropyLoss throw "TypeError: iteration over a 0-d tensor" when I verify inputs to be non-0-dimensional?

Tags: pytorch

I am using PyTorch version 1.5.0. 
When I pass an input torch tensor of size [8,21,400,400] with a target of size [8,400,400], the program raises a TypeError: iteration over a 0-d tensor. However, the dimensions of the arguments are 4 and 3 respectively.

What could be causing this error?

The traceback points to torch\tensor.py's **iter** function.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 108, in <module>
    loss, accuracy = lossLayer(pred2, targetBatch)
  File "C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py", line 462, in __iter__
    raise TypeError('iteration over a 0-d tensor')
TypeError: iteration over a 0-d tensor
```

Comment: You need to include the full stack trace and ideally a [minimal, reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The origin of the error is somewhere else, it just fails in iter, but that's probably because you're trying to iterate over a scalar tensor (for example with a for loop).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get the error because `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` just returns one `torch.Tensor`, not a pair (it doesn't return accuracy). And this tensor is 0-dimensional, i.e. one number (unless you don't override `reduction` argument to `'none'` to get per-element loss). So when you try to assign its value to two variables `loss, accuracy` python tries to iterate over this tensor variable, hence the error message. Simply use `loss = lossLayer(pred2, targetBatch)`.